# How to make Python 3.4 input insensitive?

Tags: python

So I am currently learning how to code Python right now. I decided to do a little program where it requires the user to input a word to command the program to do certain things. I have been having the issue though with putting in every variant of capitalization of the word into the code. My question is, how can I prevent this? Any help would be appreciated. Please keep in mind I am learning Python still and may not understand everything. Here is my code:

```
#This is the main program.
if choice == '1':
    print ("Not Availble Yet")
    print ("    ")
    time.sleep(2.5)
    main()

#This is if you wish to quit.
if choice =='2':
    end = input ("Are you sure you'd like to quit? ")

    #These are all the "I'd like to quit" options.
    if end == 'yes':
        print ("Closing Program in 5 seconds").lower
        time.sleep(5)
        quit
    if end == 'Yes':
        print ("Closing Program in 5 seconds").lower
        time.sleep(5)
        quit
    if end == 'yEs':
        print ("Closing Program in 5 seconds").lower
        time.sleep(5)
        quit
    if end == ("yeS"):
        print ("Closing Program in 5 seconds").lower
        time.sleep(5)
        quit
    if end == ("YES"):
        print ("Closing Program in 5 seconds").lower
        time.sleep(5)
        quit


    #These are all the "I wouldn't like to quit" options.
    if end == 'no':
        print ("Continuing Program").lower
        time.sleep(2.5)
        main()
```

Thank you!

Comment: lowercase the user input before the if/elif switches. Oh and definitely switch it to if/elif struct, which will make it much more readable.

Comment: Note that `print(...).lower` doesn't work for at least two reasons.

Comment: To sharpen the comment left by @jonrsharpe - you need to actually call the `lower()` function with parenthesis. Simply putting the word `lower` will return the function itself and not actually make the string lowercase. I'm not too sure what other reasons there are for it not to work... Perhaps he would be willing to elaborate?

Comment: Because it prints, then tries to access `None.lower` (`print` doesn't `return` anything).

Comment: @jonrsharpe - ahh.. I see - is this a python 3 specific behavior?

Comment: To a certain extent - the `print` statement in 2.x doesn't return anything either, but the parentheses would be ignored, so you'd end up seeing `<built-in method lower of str object at 0x...>` rather than `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lowercase the input:

```
end = input ("Are you sure you'd like to quit? ")
end = end.lower()
```

Then check for `"yes"` and `"no"` only.

(This is an instance of a general principle called "input normalization", a very common way to simplify programs.)

Comment: Thank you so much! Like I said, I am learning Python and wasn't able to figure this out. Your method helped me! Thanks! :D